# Superscript in TextField

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a project where I need to show a TextField with a monetary ammount

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField()
tf.htmlText = "<font size=\"30\">1</font>99";
```

This will show the 99 cents as subscript. How do I show this as superscript?

It's important that I display this in the same textfield so I don't have to worry about 2,3, or 4 digit dollar values or values with no cents. The alignment will be a lot of work.

I googled the GG Superscript fonts but because this is dealing with localization, I need to use device fonts rather thatn embedded. Also size is priority so embedding fonts is something that is not really an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use a TLFTextField from the *Text Layout Framework*.

This is from the last example at this URL:

http://flashthusiast.com/2010/05/05/getting-started-with-the-tlftextfield-class-in-actionscript-3-0-and-flash-cs5/

```
<span baselineShift='superscript'>over</span>
```

Check [this one](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Superscript___Subscript_with_Text_Layout_Framework-18175.html) too.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to install [GG Subscript & GG Superscrip](http://blog.ggshow.com/index.php/how_to_use_subscript_aamp_superscript_in?blog=11)t TrueType fonts,and after that need to restart Flash software after installed fonts.

```
 var tf:TextField = new TextField();
 tf.htmlText = "1<font face=\"GG Superscript\">99</font>";
```